# Solidity smart contract engine

Tags: blockchain, solidity

We're building our own blockchain for a school project. My part is to implement Solidity smart contracts on the blockchain. The idea was to put a Solidity smart contract engine on the validator nodes, but after weeks of searching and trying different engines I can't find a right one. Do you have any recommendations for a Solidity smart contract engine?  Thanks.

Comment: what you mean by this Solidity smart contract engine ?

Comment: Something that can read and execute smart contracts, written in the Solidity language

Comment: And what you mean by validator node?

Comment: The nodes that validate the transactions.

Comment: Note that contracts do get compiled, FROM solidity TO whatever-target, so the stuff that "reaches" e.g. the EVM on an ethereum blockchain is not plain solidity source-code but assembler-like instructions for the virtual machine (opcodes). Aka "the EVM doesnt understand solidity". 
(side-note: interesting school btw)

Comment: What do you mean by this smart contract engine. Please follow this link, you will get the idea - https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings-article/sp/2020/349700b265/1j2LggQlkvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart Contracts are execute in EVM Ethereum Virtual Machine. EVM is totally isolated and has no contact with the node. The validation process of transaction is done on the node level. So what you are looking for is the EVM which perfom these actions.

Now if you want to implement the blockchain one easiest way is to use TestRpc that will create the in memory blockchain where you can deploy the transaction and perform transaction. The validation of transaction is done internally in blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the factory pattern and create your own "engine" with built in new.

```
contract RBACFactory{
    address[] public deployedEntities;

    function createEntity(string memory name, string memory mission, string memory tokenName, 
                          string memory tokenSymbol, uint rate) public {
        address newEntity = address(new Entity(name, mission, msg.sender, tokenName, tokenSymbol, rate));
        deployedEntities.push(address(newEntity));
      
    }
    function getDeployedEntities() public view returns(address[] memory) {
        return deployedEntities;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same and i use truffle framework and ganache local blockchain. It is very easy to deploy smart contract and interact with it.

See: [truffle suite](https://www.trufflesuite.com/)